# SERVER generators using OpenAPI Generator

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using the OpenAPI Generator https://openapi-generator.tech/ for generating clients and servers as listed in the OpenApi generator list  https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators.

I have installed `openapi-generator-cli` using `npm` i.e. `$ npm install @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli -g`.

**Output on terminal:**

> /usr/local/bin/openapi-generator ->
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/bin/openapi-generator
> /usr/local/lib └── @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli@1.0.15-4.3.1

However, after I am trying to generate a ruby client from a valid `petstore.yaml` doc:

```
$ openapi-generator generate -i petstore.yaml -g ruby -o /tmp/test/
```

I keep getting an error:

> ```
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/bin/openapi-generator:3
> const {spawn} = require('child_process');
>       ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
>     at startup (node.js:136:18)
>     at node.js:966:3
> ```

**PS!** I've `$ npm -v` version **3.5.2** and `$ nodejs -v` version **v4.2.6**.

Any insight into this issue?

Thanks & looking forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually solved the issue and the error was due to the `npm` & `nodejs` version.

Previsouly, I had `$npm -v` **version 3.5.2** and `$ nodejs -v` **version v4.2.6.** .

But after I pull `node-v12.18.3` source code from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and install it from source using:

```
cd ~/node-v12.18.3
./configure
make -j 4
sudo make install
```

And then I have installed `openapi-generator-cli` using `npm` i.e. `$ npm install @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli -g`. And finally, I can generate a ruby client from a valid `petstore.yaml` doc using:

```
openapi-generator generate -i petstore.yaml -g ruby -o /tmp/test/
```

> ```
> arslan@arslan:/tmp/test$ ls
> docs  Gemfile  git_push.sh  lib  openapi_client.gemspec  Rakefile  README.md  spec
> ```

**PS!** After compiling `node-v12.18.3` from source It show up `$ npm -v`  **6.14.6**   `$ node -v`  **v12.18.3**.